# the payment button does not display the payment form, how do I do it?

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPREz.png)

```
<button wire:click="$dispatch('payment', '{{ $snapToken }}')" class="py-4 px-8 bg-amber-500">Payment</button>
                    <script>
                        Livewire.on('payment', function (snapToken) {
                            snap.pay(snapToken, {
                                onSuccess: function (result)
                                {
                                    Livewire.dispatch('emptyCart');
                                    window.location.href = "/shop";
                                },

                                onPending: function (result) {
                                    location.reload();
                                },

                                onError: function (result)
                                {
                                    location.reload()
                                }

                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

how to display the payment form on livewire

I have no difficulty finding the problem whether in livewire or in the javascript